# Is it possible to curry method calls in PHP?

Tags: php, soap, currying

I have a [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) instance generated for a WSDL file. All except one of the method invocations require the username and the password to be passed id.

Is there any way of currying the method calls so that I can omit the username and password?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you’re thinking about?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As of php 5.3 you can store an [anonymous function](http://docs.php.net/functions.anonymous) in a variable. This anonymous function can call the "original" function with some predefined parameters.

```
function foo($x, $y, $z) {
  echo "$x - $y - $z";
}

$bar = function($z) {
  foo('A', 'B', $z);
};

$bar('C');
```

edit: You can also use a closure to parametrise the creation of the anonymous function

```
function foo($x, $y, $z) {
  echo "$x - $y - $z";
}

function fnFoo($x, $y) {
  return function($z) use($x,$y) {
    foo($x, $y, $z);
  };
}

$bar = fnFoo('A', 'B');
$bar('C');
```

edit2: This also works with objects

```
class Foo {
  public function bar($x, $y, $z) {
    echo "$x - $y - $z";
  }
}

function fnFoobar($obj, $x, $z) {
  return function ($y) use ($obj,$x,$z) {
    $obj->bar($x, $y, $z);
  };
}

$foo = new Foo;
$bar = fnFoobar($foo, 'A', 'C');
$bar('B');
```

But the other suggestions using __call() and a wrapper class may be better if you want to "enhance" a complete class.

Comment: That's neat! I'm a bit rusty on PHP - I know I can enumerate the methods of an object, but can I intercept them?

Comment: You mean something like `magicTrampoline(array($obj,'methodName'), $myInterceptor)`so that whenever `$obj->methodName` is called your callback in $myInterceptor is invoked (without $obj explicitly implementing such a feature)? Would `magicTrampoline()` be allowed to return a new object?

Comment: If the `magicTrampoline()` would be able to add to the arguments passed to $obj->methodName(...), yes.

Comment: Thats a very nice way to deal with problem. But, It's not currying. If you want to see how to Curry in PHP see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609985/is-it-possible-to-curry-method-calls-in-php/51986085#answer-51986085

Answer (score 11):

Here is a class implements automatic currying and partial application:

```
class lambda
{
    private $f;
    private $args;
    private $count;
    public function __construct($f, $args = [])
    {
        if ($f instanceof lambda) {
            $this->f = $f->f;
            $this->count = $f->count;
            $this->args = array_merge($f->args, $args);
        }
        else {
            $this->f = $f;
            $this->count = count((new ReflectionFunction($f))->getParameters());
            $this->args = $args;
        }
    }

    public function __invoke()
    {
        if (count($this->args) + func_num_args() < $this->count) {
            return new lambda($this, func_get_args());
        }
        else {
            $args = array_merge($this->args, func_get_args());
            $r = call_user_func_array($this->f, array_splice($args, 0, $this->count));
            return is_callable($r) ? call_user_func(new lambda($r, $args)) : $r;
        }
    }
}
function lambda($f)
{
    return new lambda($f);
}
```

Example:

```
$add = lambda(function($a, $b) { 
    return $a + $b; 
});
$add1 = $add(1);
echo $add1(2); // 3
```

Even you can do this:

```
$int1 = lambda(function($f, $x) {
    return $f($x);
});

$successor = lambda(function($p, $f, $x) {
    return $f($p($f, $x));
}); 

$add = lambda(function($p, $q, $f, $x) {
    return $p($f, $q($f, $x));
}); 

$mul = lambda(function($p, $q, $x) {
    return $p($q($x));
}); 

$exp = lambda(function($m, $n) {
    return $n($m);
});

$int2 = $successor($int1);
$int3 = $add($int1, $int2);
$int6 = $mul($int3, $int2);
$int8 = $exp($int2, $int3);
```

Answer (score 3):

PHP doesn't have currying per se, but you can do something like that in several ways. In your specific case, something like this may work:

```
class MySoapClient extends SoapClient {
  ...
  public function __call($meth,$args) {
    if (substr($method,0,5) == 'curry') {
      array_unshift($args,PASSWORD);
      array_unshift($args,USERNAME);
      return call_user_func_array(array($this,substr($meth,5)),$args);
    } else {
      return parent::__call($meth,$args);
    }
  }
}
$soapClient = new MySoapClient();
...
// now the following two are equivalent
$soapClient->currysomeMethod($additionalArg);
$soapClient->someMethod(USERNAME,PASSWORD,$additionalArg);
```

Although here's a more general solution for currying in PHP >= 5.3:

```
$curriedMethod = function ($additionalArg) use ($soapClient) { return $soapClient->method(USERNAME,PASSWORD,$additionalArg); }

$result = $curriedMethod('some argument');
```

Answer (score 3):

I did some related research into this today. This is as close as I could get:

```
function curryAdd($x)
{
  return function($y = null) use ($x)
  {
    if (is_null($y)) return $x;
    else return curryAdd($x + $y);
  };
}

// echo curryAdd(1)(2)(3)(4);
echo curryAdd(1)
  ->__invoke(2)
  ->__invoke(3)
  ->__invoke(4)
  ->__invoke();
```

The major problem is PHP will not let you execute a closure directly on a return value (much in the same way PHP will not allow executing a method on an unbound object). However, since closures are an object of type Closure, which have a built-in method __invoke(), the above will work.

Answer (score 3):

As mentionned by Ihor, the Non-standard PHP library is interesting.
I have already implemented the same method, it is a bit different than Ihor's `curried()` function

```
function curryfy($f, $args = []) {
    $reflexion = new ReflectionFunction($f);
    $nbParams = $reflexion->getNumberOfParameters();

    return function (...$arguments) use ($f, $reflexion, $nbParams, $args) {
        if (count($args) + count($arguments) >= $nbParams) {
            return $reflexion->invokeArgs(array_merge($args, $arguments));
        }

        return curryfy($f, array_merge($args, $arguments));
    };
}
```

Usage :

```
function display4 ($a, $b, $c, $d) {
    echo "$a, $b, $c, $d\n";
};
$curry4 = curryfy('display4');
display4(1, 2, 3, 4);
$curry4(1)(2)(3)(4);
```

Answer (score 2):

Although not a very good solution, you could write a basic wrapper class that used PHPs [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) (Specifically __call) to call the actual function but append the user name and password to the argument list.

Basic example:

```
class SC
{
    private $user;
    private $pass;

    public function __construct($user, $pass)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->pass = $pass;
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments) 
    {
        $arguments = array_merge(array($this->user, $this->pass), $arguments);  
        call_user_func_array($name, $arguments);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is that the `__call` method IIRC?

Comment: call_user_func accepts a list of parameters, not an array.  Your solution will just send the curried parameters to the function as an array, not a list of arguments.  However, using call_user_func_array() will work :)

Comment: @JohnKurlak Fixed that for ya. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [partial application](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl#partialfunction-arg1) and [curry](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl#curriedfunction-withoptionalargs--false) functions from [Non-standard PHP library](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl).

Answer (score 1):

This answer [Is it possible to curry method calls in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609985/is-it-possible-to-curry-method-calls-in-php#answer-1609998) doesn't show Currying. That answer shows partial application. A nice tutorial which explains the difference between those concepts can be seen here: http://allthingsphp.blogspot.com/2012/02/currying-vs-partial-application.html

This is Currying:

```
function sum3($x, $y, $z) {
    return $x + $y + $z;
}

// The curried function    
function curried_sum3($x) {
    return function ($y) use ($x) {
        return function ($z) use ($x, $y) {
            return sum3($x, $y, $z);
        };
    };
}
```

Invoking the curried function in PHP 7

```
$result = curried_sum3(1)(2)(3); 
var_dump($result); // int 6
```

Invoking the curried function in PHP 5

```
$f1 = curried_sum3(6);
$f2 = $f1(6);
$result = $f2(6);
var_dump($result);

//OUTPUT:
int 18
```

This is Partial application:

```
function sum3($x, $y, $z) {
    return $x + $y + $z;
}

function partial_sum3($x) {
    return function($y, $z) use($x) {
        return sum3($x, $y, $z);
    };
}

//create the partial
$f1 = partial_sum3(6);
//execute the partial with the two remaining arguments
$result = $f1(6, 6);

var_dump($result);

//OUTPUT:
int 18
```

Comment: Short currying is possible as of PHP 7. So `$result = curried_sum3(1)(2)(3);` works.

Comment: @Alfred I tested it in php 7.0.1. and you are 100% right. I shall change my answer. Anyway, I find it inappropriate that this feature is not mentioned in the new features page at https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php . Can you explain why the makers of php7 didn't mentioned this?

Comment: I did not find it on a new features list either. I found this by testing on different versions. I think this is a feature of using Closures in PHP7.

Comment: @Alfred I found this in the comment section https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#122182 . It's not the first place I look for when I want to know the new features of php though. But it's interesting to see how functional programming becomes more accessible in php 7.