# Is there a way to specify only some optional function args?

Tags: php

I have a function

`public function test($arg1, $arg2 = "a", $arg3 = "b")`

Is there a way to call it specifying only `$arg1` and `$arg3` leaving `$arg2` with default value?

Comment: No, there isn't. To be able to pass `$arg3`, you must pass `$arg2` as well, but you could just pass `$arg2`'s default value? `test('hello', 'a', 'world');`

Comment: except some trickery with `func_get_args()` or using one named array as parameter? no. optional arguments *have* to be after the last mandatory argument. (maybe there's something in php7, but i'm not sure)

Comment: I would usually `test('hello', null, 'world!');` and that goes for other langs too... Maybe you can do a test to see if `$arg2` is null and based on this apply your "default" value.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Hit enter too soon, see updated...

Answer (score 2):

```
function test($arg1, $arg2 = "a", $arg3 = "b") {
    if (is_null($arg2)) $arg2 = "a";
    return $arg1.' '.$arg2.' '.$arg3;
}

echo test(1, null, 3);
```

Output:

```
1 a 3
```

Will point out too that in JavaScript this is quite common:

```
function test (input, callback) {
  $.post( "example.com/endpoint", input, function(err, data) {
    if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
      callback(true, response)
    }
    callback(null, data)
  })
}

test({
  'id': 1,
  'name': 'Mary'
}, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log.error('Error!!')
    console.log(data)
  }
  console.log.info(data)
})
```

Comment: This only works if he has access to the function and are able to change it (which we don't really know) and if `null` isn't a valid value for `$arg2`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson True that, depends on use case but may work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to using a [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

[How can I create a function dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549496/how-can-i-create-a-function-dynamically)

Comment: I think the main idea with optional arguments is that there are situations when you _do_ want to use them in. If you _never_ will send the second argument, then your solution will make sense.

Answer (score 0):

you can use currying function like this: refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1609998/6521116)

```
function foo($x, $y, $z) {
  echo "$x - $y - $z";
}

$bar = function($z) {
  foo('A', 'B', $z);
};

$bar('C');
```

also:

```
function foo($x, $y, $z) {
  echo "$x - $y - $z";
}

function fnFoo($x, $y) {
  return function($z) use($x,$y) {
    foo($x, $y, $z);
  };
}

$bar = fnFoo('A', 'B');
$bar('C');
```